# SAMPLERS: What are you using?

Tags: sound-design, sampler, editing, software

Lots to choose from out there…

I've found the integration between ProTools and [Structure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBEXXNvysmo) very smooth; it's easy to wrap my head around and actually produce some decent sounding patches in a short amount of time, which is really important to me since my schedules often don't allow for as much pre-build design as I would like.

Chime in, all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Structure is a lot of fun, and is simple enough to navigate. Much easier, I think, than [SampleTank](http://www.ikmultimedia.com/sampletank/features/). I didn't find it very sound design-friendly, as far as loading my own samples from recordings, but it was simple enough loading 3rd party libraries. Although not as famous (infamous?) as other programs, I had fun using 112dB's [Morgana](http://www.112db.com/vintage/morgana/). Much easier to navigate than SampleTank, in my opinion, and certainly less trance/house looking. What I really want to try, though, is [MachFive](http://www.motu.com/products/software/machfive). There's no demo available, though, so I suppose I'll have to save up for it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Matt - I have a friend who uses Mach Five and really enjoys it. (I didn't care for the interface, personally.)

Comment: Man, that is one ugly console (MachFive).

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of Kontakt

Answer (score 0):

I use Structure. Fits my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Kontakt is king!

Answer (score 0):

Plus 1 for Native Instruments Kontakt.